# Site can't be accessed through specific locations

Tags: dns, hosting

Since last Saturday, my website accessibility has been very fragile from my location. From the states though, everything worked perfectly. Now the situation is better, but from time to time it's unstable here and from the states it's solid.

What do you suggest me to do? Is it related to the hosting company? Domain company? Local ISPs? DNS issues?

I'm really at a loss here, need your advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your DNS issues. Trying fixing it or report this to your host provide for changing your DNS to one that is up and running. I hope this help solved your issues

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to say. You must find sample sites to compare to, such as: other site on same hosting company's servers, other site in same country, access Internet through another ISP or with/without Wi-Fi, pass through a proxy, etc. By comparing to those samples you'll MAYBE notice differences and similarities. Through logic you should then be able to exclude some hypotheses and finally nail down the problem.